# Difference between nth-of-type(1) and first-of-type pseudo-classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm curious what is the difference between nth-of-type(1) and first-of-type. From my usage they seem to do the same thing, and yet every code example will use first-of-type instead of an nth-of-type(1) if it's the first element.

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: There is no difference: https://nimb.ws/ngwlB7. Depends on the developer's usage.

Comment: The difference is 1 character in length. With ```last-of-type``` it makes "more" sense than specifying the actual last indexed number, in case this is not known.

Comment: Thanks. Still seems a bit weird to me though to give explicit keywords for every little thing that's possible, although I can understand last-of-type given your reasoning.

Comment: *Still seems a bit weird to me though to give explicit keywords for every little thing that's possible,* --> this is something common in all the languages of the world. The same thing can be achieved with a different code/syntax

Comment: @TemaniAfif Indeed, but where does it end? Why not have a[zeroIndex], followed by a[1], a[2] for an array, in addition to a[0]? I can guarantee many developers would now use this additional construct just because it's there. And if making things one character shorter were the goal, why not make a css selector with "fot" instead of first-of-type, that's even more characters shorter. The one constant in all languages is that the more ways there are to do the same thing, the more confusing it will become in terms of code readability. Anyway, I digress. I will close this question now.

Comment: I never talked about making *one character shorter*, this was not my comment and it's irrelevant

Comment: @prettyInPink: :last-of-type also has a counterpart in :nth-last-of-type(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#first-of-type-pseudo):

> Same as `:nth-of-type(1)`. The `:first-of-type` pseudo-class represents an element that is the first sibling of its type.

They are the same and we all agree with this BUT we may need them for different use cases.

Imagine the case where I need to write a SASS loop to create selector based on indexes. I will be using `:nth-of-type`

Ex:

```
@for $i from 1 through $n {
 .container > div:nth-of-type(#{$i}) { ... }
}
```

And sometimes I only need to target the first element so I can simply use `first-of-type` which will make the code easier to read.

Comment: I accept this answer. I don't believe though first-of-type is easier to read, unless someone failed to understand what nth-of-type did. nth-of-type(1) to me seems pretty obvious.

Comment: @user4779 *nth-of-type(1) to me seems pretty obvious* --> it's not, for people coming from other fields `nth-of-type(0)` can also be obvious so imagine all the confusing around the indexes. first-of-type is obvious since there is no confusion

Comment: @user4779 you have to also consider historical reasons. the first selector was only `first-child` and then later are added the other selector like nth-child, nth-of-type, etc so it doesn't make sense to remove `first-of-child` to keep the new ones but it does make sense to add `first-of-type` to have consistency

Comment: but wouldn't you want someone new to css to be forced to confront how indexing works within css, before they went into production under false assumptions, relying upon things like first-of-type? Little realizations like this would force them to become familiar with the domain before they could do too much damage in production code with that level of ignorance.

Comment: @user4779 *to become familiar with the domain* --> CSS is so wide than what you think, I see people working for more than 5 years with CSS and still don't understand a lot of things. Also some people may never need to use nth-of-type in their life. Do you know that a selector called `:only-child` exist? probably not and maybe you will never need it

Comment: @Temanfi Afif That's a good question, and I realize we digress from my question, which you have kindly answered.. Indeed CSS is widely used, until recently I had not a clue how it works other than trial and error, but I do wonder if it had less ways to 'do the same thing', if the pain could have been minimized. Anyway, I guess it is what it is, and I appreciate you highlighting the historical context too as to why it's like that, which is interesting

Comment: @user4779: It's worth noting that the concept of matching the nth child was introduced in CSS2 as :first-child *only*, and we didn't see :last-child or :nth-child() until CSS3. I guess you *could* deduce that :first-of-type, albeit equally new to CSS3, was added as a counterpart to :first-child (I don't know that, you'd have to ask the WG). But I think it just boils down to the word "first" being more intuitive than "nth(1)" to most people. "nth(1)" just seems clunky, even if it may seem obvious that it means "first".

Comment: If anything I'm a little irritated that they didn't add functional :first-child(of S) and :last-child(of S) so I wouldn't have to write :nth-child(1 of S) and :nth-last-child(1 of S).